# Adding prefix and postfix to matching regular expression

Tags: regular-expression

Dear fellow Developers,
I would like to quote variables having `@` inside like `test@mail.org`, but not starting with `@` like `@var1`, `@var2`.
Does Vi/Vim/Neovim have any option to inspect the matched pattern and create a pre- and postfix to `test@mail.org`: `"test@mail.org"` ?
`:%s/ [a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]* / \"*\" /`
does not work due to `\"*\"`.

If Vi/Vim/Neovim has no such feature, what tools would you recommend for portability?
I know C++ has a feature to inspect the matched regex as a string for manipulation, but I would like to have a more pluggable solution for vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `\0` to insert the contents of the match in the substitution:

```
:%s/\<[a-zA-Z0-9.]\+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]*\>/"\0"/g
```

Note that, given that you gave an example of an email address, I added `.` to your character classes so that the expression will match these, but it won't *only* match email addresses. e.g. It *would* match `a@a`.

I also changed the white spaces into start/end word atoms: `\<`, `\>` so that it will successfully match email addresses abutting punctuation, and added a `g` flag so that more than one match can be found on each line.

Comment: Ive always used & because it’s easier to type than \0—are the functionally equivalent (ie worth suggesting as an alternative in the answer)? Or is there a subtle difference (and i should stop using &)?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble From a short glimpse at the [source](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/2efc44b3f0b6bd8307cb281af095e08e15ab1c24/src/regexp.c#L2076-L2087) I would say '&' and '\0' are the equivalent.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The two are equivalent. I didn't mention `&` in my answer because I don't think it really adds much benefit to know two different ways of doing it, and it makes the answer more complicated.

I personally use `\0` because a). I learned it first b). I like the relation to `\1` et al. and the similarity with `awk`, and c). as someone who doesn't type "correctly" it's not any harder to type than `&`. (In fact, it's almost identical, but slightly easier because it's not a chord) ;)